# React Flatlist for few specific data types with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In my typescript react-native project I am creating a component wrapper ContentList. The purpose of this wrapper is to unify styling and behavior across multiple lists of my app. This component ContentList is accepting props: `data` and `renderItem`, which are both passed to react FlatList component.

The problem is that Typescript asks me to define types for `data` and `renderItem` props. I know that data passed to this list will be of type `Apple`, `Orange`, or `Melon`, so I tried the following code:

```js
...
type ListCompatibleObject = Apple | Orange | Melon;
type ContentListProps = Pick<FlatListProps<ListCompatibleModel>, 'data' | 'renderItem'>;

const ContentList = ({ data, renderItem }: ContentListProps) => {

   return (
           <View style={styles.container}>
               <FlatList
                  data={data}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                  ...
```

Everything works as expected. But when I define `renderItem` in a parent component like this:

```js
...
const renderItem = ({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<Apple>) => (
        <SessionCard sessionData={item} openDetail={openDetailScreen} />
    );


return <ContentList renderItem={renderItem}  ... />

...
```

Then Typescript complains that the function interface of my provided function and defined type is not compatible. Error is here:

```
Type '({ item }: ListRenderItemInfo<Apple>) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem<ListCompatibleModel>'.
```

I am debugging this problem for two hours already. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the reason to use renderItem function in parent component?

Comment: For different data, I want to render different Components. For example, I want to initialize ContentList inside of AppleScreen and with renderItem function render a AppleCard component. For Orange, I would like to render OrangeCard, etc...

Comment: I have another approach in mind: 

Why don't you define types of data Array in parent. 
let fruits: Array<Orange | Melon | Apple> = fetchedData;
That array pass into <ContentList data={fruits}... />
and then use renderItem as
renderItem = ({item, index } => {
if(typeof item === Orange) {
return <OrangeCard />
}
if(typeof item === Melon) {
return <MelonCard />
}
etc...
Or you can use switch
})

Comment: Because the AppleCard and Orange cards don't have same properties. For example <AppleCard sweetness={apple.sweetness} onpress={AppleNavigation.navigate(...)} ... />  and <OrangeCard peeled={orange.peeled} onPress={OrangeNavigation.navigate(...)} ... />. The AppleNavigation and OrangeNavigation come from different navigators etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the component `ContentList` and `ContentListProps` generic:

```js
...
type ListCompatibleModel = Apple | Orange | Melon;
type ContentListProps<T> = Pick<FlatListProps<T>, 'data' | 'renderItem'>;

const ContentList = <T extends ListCompatibleModel>({ data, renderItem}: ContentListProps<T>) => {
    return (
            <FlatList
               data={data}
               renderItem={renderItem}
               ...
```

Then everything works perfectly.